# Exact axis ticks and labels in R Lattice xyplot

Tags: r, lattice, axis-labels

I'm creating many plots (each as a separate image) that all must have identical axis limits. When using ylim, the tick marks are awkwardly placed at the extreme edges and tick labels are omitted for the extreme values.

```
library(lattice)
x=1:100
y=10+20*(runif(100))
xyplot(y~x)                 # Case 1 - automatic ylim
xyplot(y~x, ylim=c(10,20))  # Case 2 - specified ylim
```

In Case 1, the axis ticks and labels are automatically generated at (y=10,15,20,25,30). All tick marks are labeled, and there is some vertical padding for the extreme tick marks (y=10 and y=30) in the plot rectangle.

In Case 2, when I specify ylim values, the tick marks are generated at (y=10,12,14,16,18,20) but labels appear only for (y=12,14,16,18). Tick labels are missing at the extremes. Also, there is no vertical padding for the extreme tick marks in the plot rectangle.

Is there a way to specify ylim and still have the tick marks and labels come out similarly to Case 1?

More generally, when specifying ylim:
1. how can you specify exactly where each tick mark goes? 
2. how can you specify exactly which tick marks get labeled?

Comment: 'xyplot' typically pads the x and y limits to extend 4% above and below the range of x.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get your tick marks and labels where you want, you can do something along the lines of:

```
xyplot(
  y~x,
  ylim=c(10,20),
  scales=list(
    y=list(
      at=seq(10,20,2),
      labels=c("a","","b","","c","") )
    )
)
```

The padding issue, I'm not sure about how to address except for manually adjusting the `ylim=` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Padding is controlled in lattice.options with axis.padding. See ?lattice.options

Comment: put your short answer in comment

Comment: Sorry, I can't yet as don't have 50 reputation. Did try

Comment: @Damirchi It is not good practice to put answers in comments, even if they are very short.

Comment: @Irenabyss It is fine to have a short answer, but do refrain from posting things like clarification questions until you reach the limit.  This answer is fine, but it could do with some expanding (like explaining the options the OP asked for).